# Waavi/translation source set to database, still translating from the files

Tags: laravel

I am using package Waavi/translation https://github.com/Waavi/translation

https://github.com/Waavi/translation#translations-source says

> This package allows you to load translation from the regular Laravel localization files (in /resources/lang), from the database, from cache or in a mix of the previous for development. You may configure the desired mode of operation through the translator.php config file and/or the TRANSLATION_SOURCE environment variable. Accepted values are:
>
> 'files' To load translations from Laravel's language files (default)
>
> 'database' To load translations from the database

I have set TRANSLATION_SOURCE to database and when I do this

trans('pagination.previous');

its still loading from files instead of database.

Anyone who has experience with this package knows what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing TRANSLATION_SOURCE to 'database', TRANSLATION_CACHE_ENABLED to 'false'. Then 'php artisan config:cache' to clear cache.